# Infix to Postfix approach

Tags: algorithm, stack

What would be the postfix notation of the expression

```
((A+B)*C-(D-E)^(F+G))
```

I am getting the answer `AB+C*DE-FG+^-`

My steps according to PEMDAS are

```
((AB+)*C-(DE-)^(FG+))
((AB+)*C-(DE-FG+^))
(AB+C*)-(DE-FG+^)
```

But the book says the answer should be

```
AB+C*DE--FG+^
```

Could anyone please tell me where I got it wrong, or possibly the given solution is wrong?

Comment: where is the solution provided?

Comment: I have a book that has this answer

Comment: I think the book is wrong..or probably there is a misprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about precedence and associativity of c operators. you can follow this link.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Hint:In your case precedence of ^ (XOR operator) will be least.

Comment: ^ this means xor I was thinking it as exponent Thanks suresh

Comment: i think this solved your problem. you can  upvote and mark my answer as solved so that others will find it helpful.

Comment: ya but i am thinking how would you represent exponent would there be any symbol or pow function would be used

Comment: in c/c++ ^ symbol is used for XOR operation. There's no operator for power, you'll need to use pow function from math.h